# No content is printed for urlopen on request

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python **version 3.4**

When I try:

```
import urllib.request as urlrq
from urllib.request import Request
import certifi

req = Request('https://camelcamelcamel.com/popular.xml?deal=1', headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})

resp = urlrq.urlopen(req)

print(content.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Then nothing is printed although there is content in that xml.
Anything that can be updated so content is fetched from that xml?

Comment: don't you get error message ? But you should get error. And you should add this error in question.

Comment: Writing a __proper__ [mcve] would have solved the issue - as often...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a variable called `content` in your print statement, however; from the code shown, that variable is never initialized.

I've modified your code slightly and this works, using the correct variables.

```
import urllib.request as urlrq
from urllib.request import Request

req = Request('https://camelcamelcamel.com/popular.xml?deal=1', headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
resp = urlrq.urlopen(req)
print(resp.read().decode('utf-8'))
```